# Adding my face to my web-site in Google's search result

Tags: rich-snippets, google-authorship, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm trying to accomplish the rich snippet to the template of my future web-site. The data format is `review` and I used the microdata formatting to add all necessary information to the web-page. The [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) delivered rating, author information and review date:

[image]

However there is no my face image and the sections related to authorship are empty:

[image]

I made all that recommended to link my Google+ profile to the web-site:

[image]

I did something wrong? Or I will not be able to see my face in the test tools ever and it will be in the real SERP?

Answer (score 1):

If it says the page does not contain authorship markup in the rich snippet testing tool then yes, you've done something wrong. Enter your Google+ profile URL in the box provided and see where the problem lies.

You need to link to your Google+ profile using syntax `<a href="https://plus.google.com/NNNNNNNNNNNNNN?rel=author">Google Plus</a>`

You won't be able to have review schema and authorship schema showing in your search result listings either - it will be one or the other. We've tried this before but I think Google only allow a limited amount of schema just so websites can't go overboard with their pages.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Couple comments: If I use my G+ account link and press 'Verify authorship' I just throw over to the beginning of the same page - no any additional message shown. You could try your self: https://plus.google.com/107295573220344975998 and http://digitalcameraport.com/item.php. The second part of your answer I just didn't understand. Could you chew it over?

Comment: There isn't any authorship markup on /item.php - that's why the testing tool says it isn't there. You need to link to your Google+ profile using `rel="author"` for example. The second part just basically meant that you won't be able to have your Google+ picture and the star ratings visible in search results at the same time.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't find such information in the docs. However that worked! Thanks!